# Please I'm new to python and I'm trying to do a recipe app using Django. I encountered an error which is "UnboundLocalError: local variable form

Tags: python, django

[this is the picture of my views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cPtw.jpg)

When I ran the code I saw an this error in the browser
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only create form if your request is POST.
so if you try to call your view with get method form variable is not created.

---

this is your code I'm gonna walk you through it.

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f"{username}, your account has been created!")
            return redirect('recipes-home')
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request,'users/Register.html',{'form',form})
```

if a user post something to your register view this happens:
they go in this condition:

```py
form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
    messages.success(request,f"{username}, your account has been created!")
    return redirect('recipes-home')
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()
```

if data is valid they get redirected. else an empty form is created and then this line:

```py
return render(request,'users/Register.html',{'form',form})
```

works because it's out of if condition and an empty form exists.
but if a user tries to request the view with get method this code executes because condition checks for "POST":

```py
def register(request):
    return render(request,'users/Register.html',{'form',form})
```

so now you can see that your code can't understand where did the `form` came from.

you can use this to make your code work.

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f"{username}, your account has been created!")
            return redirect('recipes-home')
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request,'users/Register.html',{'form',form})
```